# SQL Server : combining COUNT(*) for different tables at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012, inner-join

I have a few queries that I would like to combine into **ONE** query in order to not have to call out to the server multiple times.

An example of the queries I am using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS mailCount1 
FROM [WebContact].[dbo].[memberEmails]  
WHERE contactdatetime > '01/01/06'
  AND contactdatetime < '02/01/06'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS mailCount2
FROM [WebContact].[dbo].[otherEmails]
WHERE contactdatetime > '01/01/06'
  AND contactdatetime < '02/01/06'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS mailCount3 
FROM [WebContact].[dbo].[memberEmails]  
WHERE contactdatetime > '02/01/06'
  AND contactdatetime < '03/01/06'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS mailCount4
FROM [WebContact].[dbo].[otherEmails]
WHERE contactdatetime > '02/01/06'
  AND contactdatetime < '03/01/06'

etc etc...
```

So as the examples above, only thing that changes are:

- The `FROM` (`memberEmails` & `otherEmails`)
- The `>` & `<` months (01/01/06, 02/01/06 | 02/01/06, 03/01/06 | etc...)

Is this possible to do with a single query?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `vb.net`? This is strictly a SQL question.

Answer (score 3):

First, use `group by` and just use two queries:

```
select year(contactdatetime) as yyyy, month(contactdatetime) as mm, count(*)
from WebContact].[dbo].[memberEmails]
group by year(contactdatetime), month(contactdatetime);
```

and:

```
select year(contactdatetime) as yyyy, month(contactdatetime) as mm, count(*)
from WebContact].[dbo].[otherEmails]
group by year(contactdatetime), month(contactdatetime);
```

Then, if you like, you can combine these into a single query:

```
select coalesce(me.yyyy, oe.yyyy) as yyyy, coalesce(me.mm, oe.mm) as mm,
       coalesce(me.cnt, 0) as memberemailcnt,
       coalesce(oe.cnt, 0) as otheremailcnt
from (select year(contactdatetime) as yyyy, month(contactdatetime) as mm, count(*) as cnt
      from WebContact].[dbo].[memberEmails]
      group by year(contactdatetime), month(contactdatetime)
     ) me full outer join
     (select year(contactdatetime) as yyyy, month(contactdatetime) as mm, count(*) as cnt
      from WebContact].[dbo].[otherEmails]
      group by year(contactdatetime), month(contactdatetime)
     ) oe
     on me.yyyy = oe.yyyy and me.mm = oe.mm;
```

A `full outer join` is not necessary if both tables have data for all months.

Comment: Do any of these take into consideration the > and < WHERE/AND's?

Comment: I'm not able to get the last one to fire. Although the first 2 did fire just fine.

Comment: @StealthRT . . . These produce separate rows for each year/month.  The only obvious problem I see in the third query is that `count(*)` doesn't have a column alias.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there any effect for `coalesce` with only one expression?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't check the syntax or performance but you can do something like this,

```
     WITH cte (
        countvalue
        ,description
        )
    AS (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
            ,'mailCount1'
        FROM [WebContact].[dbo].[memberEmails]
        WHERE contactdatetime > '01/01/06'
            AND contactdatetime < '02/01/06'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT COUNT(*)
            ,'mailCount2'
        FROM [WebContact].[dbo].[otherEmails]
        WHERE contactdatetime > '01/01/06'
            AND contactdatetime < '02/01/06'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT COUNT(*)
            ,'mailCount3'
        FROM [WebContact].[dbo].[memberEmails]
        WHERE contactdatetime > '02/01/06'
            AND contactdatetime < '03/01/06'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT COUNT(*)
            ,'mailCount4'
        FROM [WebContact].[dbo].[otherEmails]
        WHERE contactdatetime > '02/01/06'
            AND contactdatetime < '03/01/06'
        )

    SELECT mailCount1
    ,mailCount2
    ,mailCount3
    ,mailCount4
FROM (
    SELECT countvalue
        ,description
    FROM cte
    ) d
pivot(max(countvalue) FOR description IN (mailCount1, mailCount2, mailCount3, mailCount4)) piv;
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Better syntax would be to have that first select in the FROM and use CROSS JOIN for the others.

Comment: please see updated answer, changed it to use CTE instead of sub-query in select.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @emailCount table(tablename varchar(20), year int, month int, qty int) 

insert into @emailCount
select 'memberEmails', year(contactdatetime), month(contactdatetime), count(*)
from [WebContact].[dbo].[memberEmails]   
group by year(contactdatetime), month(contactdatetime)

insert into @emailCount
select 'otherEmails',year(contactdatetime), month(contactdatetime), count(*)
from [WebContact].[dbo].[otherEmails]
group by year(contactdatetime), month(contactdatetime)

select tablename, year, month, qty from @emailCount
```

Add `WHERE` clause if needed to restrict date ranges. (edit- simplified to use year() and month() functions.)